# accessors problem

Tags: c#, accessor

I was wondering if it was impossible to set up an accessor to allow you to access the accessor's variable..
Example of an error:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Object.name = "test"; //Can't access the object's subproperties
    }

    Objec ob = new Objec();
    public Objec Object
    {
        get { return ob; }
        set { ob = value; }
    }
class Objec
{
    string name;
    string value;
}
```

Is there anyway to do the above (other than making accessors for every value)?
Thanks,
Max

EDIT: Here is a better example

```
    public void Main()
    {
        //Now I can't change the X or Y properties, this will display an error
        ThePoint.X = 10;
        //To change the x value, I need to do the following:
        ThePoint = new Point(10,0);
    }

    private Point Poi = new Point();
    public Point ThePoint
    {
        get { return Poi; }
        set { Poi = value; }
    }
```

Is there a way to make 'ThePoint.X' work (without just publicly displaying 'Poi')?

Comment: Can you be more clear. This doesn't really make sense to me as a C# language question unless you just have several mistakes. However, you might be interested in Auto-Implemented Properties if this is about C#. -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: `public void Object` doesn't make sense.  Should it be `public Objec Object`?

Comment: The better example is sufficient to show us what the real problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your actual question "Is there anyway to do the above (other than making accessors for every value)?" is NO.

Guessing a bit on your intentions, you seem to want to follow a design pattern known as [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) (your class is an abstraction around the implementation of `Object` and/or `Point`).  You will only expose to your class' audience the pieces of the original implementation that you want, in your question's case, every value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you didn't post full code. I would imagine right now you can't access Objec.name because it is a private variable (and thus inaccessible from Main()).

Try:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        instance.Child.ChildValue = "something";
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    // The following code declares Public Properties 
    // rather than private variables.

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyChild Child { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Child = new MyChild();
    }
}

public class MyChild
{
    public string ChildValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, with your new example, it's clear what the problem is: you're acting as if Point were a class when it's actually a struct.

When you say `ThePoint.X = 10;`, all you're doing is changing the X for a *copy* of the original point.  That's because a struct is always passed by value, not reference.

In short, the error is in your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the name and value variables public to get your solution to compile.  Or better yet, use automatic properties.

Comment: Uh, no.  The whole point of properties is to keep the syntax of public fields while offering a way to keep those fields private.

Comment: Steven, I understand that, but I'm answering his question on how to get it to work, not how to make it the best from a design perspective.

Comment: If you're recommending something that you know is a bad idea, please say so.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to specify the `public` for every class member you want to expose in C#.**

According to the [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> Class members, including nested
>   classes and structs, can be public,
>   protected internal, protected,
>   internal, or private. The access level
>   for class members and struct members,
>   including nested classes and structs,
>   is private by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes:

```
public void Main()
{
    Object.name = "test"; //Can access the object's properties now...
}

Objec ob = new Objec();

public Objec Object
{
    get { return ob; }
    set { ob = value; }
}

public class Objec
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string value {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, although to be fair, that's because you copied the errors from the original.

Comment: @Steven, thanks, I made the corrections.  All I wanted to do was illustrate the auto-implemented properties, got careless...!

Comment: It still doesn't work at all.  Again, this is mostly due to the source.